# Access to QueryString / Session from a static Method?

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

I use ASP.Net and a static WebMethod / PageMethod to do some async work.
My question is how to access my queryStrings and Session variables here?

I tried "HttpContext.Current" and a lot of information is available here, but not my QueryString nor my Session and I don't know why.

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public static object Update(string time)
    {
        string timer;
        string lastBidder;
        string price;

        //Countdown timer
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(time);
        dt = dt.AddSeconds(-1.0);
        timer = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

        int auctionID = 6;
        if (!int.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"], out auctionID))
            throw new Exception("Seitenaufruf ohne ID");

        Business.AuctionHandling ah = new Business.AuctionHandling();
        DAL.Auktion auktion = ah.GetSingleAuction(auctionID);

        price = auktion.AktuellerPreis.ToString("###0.00");

        //this.gvHistory.DataBind();

        List<DAL.Biethistorie> his = ah.GetBidHistoryForAuction(auctionID);
        if (his.Count > 0)
        {
            lastBidder = his[0].Benutzer.Benutzername;
            //History fett
            //gvHistory.Rows[0].Font.Bold = true;
            //gvHistory.Rows[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#3B4D5F");
            //lblHöchstesGebot.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            lastBidder = Helper.StringHelper.AuctionDeatil_NoBidder;
            //lblHöchstesGebot.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }

        return new
        {
            valueTimer = timer,
            valuePrice = price,
            valueLastBidder = lastBidder
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out of interest why aren't you just passing the information you need to the web method as you are calling it?

Comment: I agree, this will also make it easier to unit test the static methods, but shouldn't this still be a comment?

Comment: I don't care about the moment for unit tests. So you mean access the session and query string in javascript and pass it in the variable?

Answer (score 8):

The QueryString is in the Request property.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString
```

But the Session is in there:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I had a number of static methods I was using to help manage my Cache and Session.  Luckily, you can pass a reference to the Cache or Session into your moethods like this:

```
public static void DoSomething(System.Web.SessionState sessn)
```

And then access your session by using the sessn object.

Comment: How I can get a sessionstate object from javascript

Comment: Sorry.. I'm not too sure about that one.  Session is usually handled by the server.  Maybe include it into a hidden field as JSON or something?  That might be a good topic few a new question and someone with more javascript experience than I can tackle it.

Answer (score -1):

THIS IS LATE REPLY BUT WILL HELP OTHERS AND MARK IT AS ANSWER ..well u have to post your code on how you are calling that Update method. coz i am doing the same and im getting my querystring and the trick for that is you have to pass that in alongwith your get or post call like following

$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "" + getDirectoryPath() + getCurrentPageName() + "/SavePatientEpisodes?ApplicationInstanceID=" + querystring,
                        data: JSON.stringify({ PatientOne: patientOneData, PatientTwo: patientTwoData, PatientOneID: $("#tbPatient1").val(), PatientTwoID: $("#tbPatient2").val() }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                        }
                    });

AND ACCESS IT as BELOW

_
        Public Shared Function SavePatientEpisodes(ByVal PatientOne As List(Of Episode), ByVal PatientTwo As List(Of Episode), ByVal PatientOneID As String, ByVal PatientTwoID As String) As String
            Dim dd As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("ApplicationInstanceID")

```
        Dim lang As Integer = toInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("UserID"))
```

return ""
End Function